Getting error of "Called function does not exist in the contract" in the contract in which this function exists
I have created a Swapper to interact with Curve Pool for adding liquidity and withdrawing it from the Pool + interact with Gauge Contract to deposit / withdraw LPs.
Here is the code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.8.23;

import { SafeERC20, IERC20 } from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

import { ISwapper } from "../../interfaces/ISwapper.sol";
import { ICurvePool } from "../../interfaces/ICurvePool.sol";

/// @title CurveSwapper
/// @notice The contract to manage adding liquidity and removing liquidity from specific Curve Pool
/// (with only 2 coins).
/// And deposit, withdraw LPs into Gauge contract + getting rewards from it.
contract CurveSwapper is ISwapper {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

    /// @notice The address of specific Curve Pool
    ICurvePool public immutable curvePool;
    /// @notice The address of Gauge contract
    ICurvePool public immutable gauge;
    /// @notice The address of collateral asset
    IERC20 public immutable coll; // LP address

    /// @notice The address of reward token - CRV
    address public immutable token;
    /// @notice The address of underlying asset
    address public immutable underlyingAsset;
    /// @notice The address of SwapManager
    address public immutable swapManager;

    /// @notice The position of coin in Curve Pool
    int128 public immutable coinPosition;

    /// @notice Errors
    error CurveSwapper__ZeroAddress();
    error CurveSwapper__OnlySwapManager();

    /// @notice Modifier to check if the caller is the SwapManager
    modifier onlySwapManager() {
        if (msg.sender != swapManager) {
            revert CurveSwapper__OnlySwapManager();
        }
        _;
    }

    /// @notice Constructor for setting immutable addresses
    constructor(
        address _swapManager,
        address _curvePool,
        address _gauge,
        address _token, 
        address _coll,
        address _underlyingAsset // USDC
    ) {
        if (
            _swapManager == address(0) || _curvePool == address(0) || _gauge == address(0)
                || _token == address(0) || _coll == address(0) || _underlyingAsset == address(0)
        ) {
            revert CurveSwapper__ZeroAddress();
        }

        swapManager = _swapManager;
        curvePool = ICurvePool(_curvePool);
        gauge = ICurvePool(_gauge);
        token = _token;
        coll = IERC20(_coll);
        underlyingAsset = _underlyingAsset;

        if (underlyingAsset == ICurvePool(curvePool).coins(0)) {
            coinPosition = 0;
        } else {
            coinPosition = 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice Provides underlying asset into the Curve Pool to mint LPs and burn LPs from Curve
     * Pool to get underlying asset back
     * @dev Only SwapManager can call this function
     * @param tokenIn The address of input token
     * @param amount The amount of input token
     * @param recipient The address of recipient to get LPs or underlying asset
     * @return tokenAmountOut The amount of output LPs or underlying asset
     */
    function swap(
        address tokenIn,
        uint256 amount,
        address recipient
    )
        external
        onlySwapManager
        returns (uint256 tokenAmountOut)
    {
        if (tokenIn == underlyingAsset) {
            uint256[2] memory amounts = [amount, 0];
            if (coinPosition != 0) {
                amounts[0] = 0;
                amounts[1] = amount;
            }
            IERC20(underlyingAsset).approve(address(curvePool), amount);
            ICurvePool(curvePool).add_liquidity(amounts, 0);
            coll.transfer(recipient, tokenAmountOut);
        } else {
            coll.approve(address(curvePool), amount);
            tokenAmountOut =
                ICurvePool(curvePool).remove_liquidity_one_coin(amount, coinPosition, 0, recipient);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @notice Deposits LPs into Gauge contract
     * @dev Only SwapManager can call this function
     * @param lpAmount The amount of LPs to deposit
     */
    function deposit(uint256 lpAmount) external onlySwapManager {
        coll.approve(address(gauge), lpAmount);
        ICurvePool(gauge).deposit(lpAmount, address(this), false);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Withdraws LPs from Gauge contract
     * @dev Only SwapManager can call this function
     * @param lpAmount The amount of LPs to withdraw
     */
    function withdraw(uint256 lpAmount) external onlySwapManager {
        ICurvePool(gauge).withdraw(lpAmount, msg.sender, false);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Claims rewards from Gauge contract, gets amount of reward token and send it to
     * SwapManager
     * @dev Only SwapManager can call this function
     */
    function claim_rewards() external onlySwapManager {
        ICurvePool(gauge).claim_rewards(address(this), msg.sender);
    }
}

And when I execute "swap" function, unfortunately I get an "Error Message: Called function does not exist in the contract", but interface is similar to contract which I am going to call.
Thats pool on Arbitrum USDE/USDC with address 0x1c34204fcfe5314dcf53be2671c02c35db58b4e3.
Interface for ICurvePool.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity =0.8.23;

/// @title ICurvePool
/// @notice Defines the basic interface for Curve Pool contract and Gauge contract interaction.
interface ICurvePool {
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external returns (bool);

    function coins(uint256 i) external view returns (address);

    function add_liquidity(uint256[2] memory _amounts, uint256 _min_mint_amount) external;

    function add_liquidity(
        uint256[3] memory amounts,
        uint256 _min_mint_amount
    )
        external
        returns (uint256);

    function add_liquidity(
        uint256[4] memory amounts,
        uint256 _min_mint_amount
    )
        external
        returns (uint256);

    function remove_liquidity_one_coin(
        uint256 _burn_amount,
        int128 i,
        uint256 _min_received,
        address _receiver
    )
        external
        returns (uint256);

    function deposit(uint256 lpAmount, address user, bool claim_rewards) external;

    function withdraw(uint256 lpAmount, address user, bool claim_rewards) external;

    function claim_rewards(address user, address recipient) external;
}

Maybe the problem is that solidity compiler generates the wrong selector and by the wrong selector does not call the correct function in the Curve Pool contract
